# Trying to make Multiple Client Server in Java?

Tags: java, sockets

For some reason when  I run my server code, the server window pops up but then it freezes and doesn't allow me to do anything. I've experimented with my code and it seems that the `while` loop is the problem because when I remove it, it works fine. But I require the `while` loop for serving many clients. Here is the code:

NOTE: The variable `numClients` has already been initialized and instantiated somewhere else.

```
  try{

        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8000);
        textArea.append("Server started on " + new Date() + "\n");          

        while(numClients <= 5){

         Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

         InetAddress inetAddress = socket.getInetAddress();

             textArea.append("Client \"" + inetAddress.getHostName() + "\" has                          
                             connected!");
         textArea.append("The IP address of \"" + inetAddress.getHostName() +     
                         "\" is   " + inetAddress.getHostAddress());    

         HandleClient task = new HandleClient(socket);
         new Thread(task).start();

         numClients++;

    }
}
catch(IOException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The method call: `serverSocket.accept()` is blocking, meaning it will stop the current thread, until somebody connects. This mean no user input will be received if it is being done in the same thread that is reading the input.

This means that without the `while` loop you will receive one connection and leave this code, 
but with the `while` loop you will keep blocking and receiving new connections.

To solve your problem you need to run the `while` loop on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is when you call `Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();` the thread 'blocks' until it receives a connected `Socket`. And cause your GUI and `Socket` are contained in the same thread, your GUI appears unresponsive.

What you want to do is look into threading and run connection acceptance code in a separate thread to your GUI. That way your GUI remains independent of your `Socket` thread and won't get blocked while your `Socket` is waiting for connections.

Answer (score 0):

You should not try to have multiple threads accepting connections on the same port.  You should have one thread accepting (multiple client requests are queued at the port) and you can then spawn a new thread to handle each accepted connection.

See:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/socket-140484.html#multi
- [thread-based serversocket](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0320__Network/ThreadbasedServerSocket.htm)